# Package imbalance: error "some of the class attribute(s) not found in dataset"

Tags: r

I want to balance my data with the `imbalance` package using the oversampling code.
When trying this code, it gives me the error:

```
new_train <- oversample(train, method = "ADASYN")
```

**Error code**:

> Error in checkDatasetClass(dataset, classAttr) :    some of the class
>   attribute(s) not found in dataset

my data looks like this:

```
> head(train)
    case           country   steering     type           group 
1  bad              Europe      LL         AUT             3
2 good              Europe      LL         AUT             2
3 good              Europe      LL         AUT             2
4 good              Europe      LL         SCH             2
5 good              Europe      RL         AUT             2
6 good              Europe      LL         AUT             1

> str(train)
'data.frame':   11479 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ case : Factor w/ 2 levels "bad",..: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ country: Factor w/ 9 levels "Africa","LatinAmerica",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ steering: Factor w/ 2 levels "LL","RL": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ type: Factor w/ 2 levels "AUT","SCH": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ group: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 2 2 2 2 1 2 3 3 2 ...
```

I already removed the NA's with

```
which(is.na(train))
train <- na.omit(train)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify your target variable. For example:

```r
serhat_simsek <- oversample(train, method = "ADASYN",classAttr = "group")
```